# How do I find out what app an apk file is for, WITHOUT installing any software?

Tags: android

How do I find out what app an apk file is for, WITHOUT installing any software?

Uploading the file to [Virus Total](http://virustotal.com) doesn't help.

I opened an apk file in winrar and need to know what string to search for to search the file contents.

Comment: What do you expect to see, the app name (in which language?) or what other information? Virus Total shows you the APK `Package Name` which you can use to check if the app is in Play Store (if it is the same): `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=` and the append the shown package name.

Comment: I expect to see the app name or package name in english. Virus Total cannot recognise the file.

Comment: The package name is shown. Check the Details page section "Android Info" - for example https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/74724a3b212b43b60b3780767cf22276292cad5c198990c45f079a0512d3aa81/details shows `com.simplemobiletools.gallery` as package name. It it does not show the Android Info section it is not a valid APK file.

Comment: I see it now in the details tab if I scroll down to Android Info. Thank you.